# Need help to combine this two queries:

Tags: mysql, sql

```
"select m.id, m.total_amount
from table_main m
inner join table_item i on m.id = i.ref_id
where journal_id = 10 and period = 24
group by m.id
order by purchase_invoice_id desc"

"select i.item_id, sum(i.debit_amount) as debit, sum(i.credit_amount) as credit
from table_main m
inner join table_item i on m.id = i.ref_id
where i.item_id in
(select id
from table_main
where journal_id = 10 and period = 24 )
and m.journal_id in (18, 20)  and m.posted='1' and i.gl_type in ('chk', 'pmt')
group by i.item_id"
```

m.id = i.item_id

i just need to combine this two table where m.id = i.item_id

Comment: How do you want to combine them? Show sample data and the desired result.

Answer (score 2):

Just join them:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.total_amount, IFNULL(t2.debit, 0) AS debit, IFNULL(t2.credit, 0) AS credit
FROM (
    select m.id, m.total_amount, purchase_invoice_id
    from table_main m
    inner join table_item i on m.id = i.ref_id
    where journal_id = 10 and period = 24
    group by m.id
) AS t1
LEFT JOIN (
    select i.item_id, sum(i.debit_amount) as debit, sum(i.credit_amount) as credit
    from table_main m
    inner join table_item i on m.id = i.ref_id
    where i.item_id in
    (select id
    from table_main
    where journal_id = 10 and period = 24 )
    and m.journal_id in (18, 20)  and m.posted='1' and i.gl_type in ('chk', 'pmt')
    group by i.item_id
) AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.item_id
order by t1.purchase_invoice_id desc
```

Comment: bro i got another question, my t1's table length is longer than t2's, how can null values appear just to get the length of the longer table?

Comment: Use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `JOIN`.